# Add alt-tag to slider - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, tags, slider, alt

For wordpress the current theme i'm working with has no alt tags specified for the slider images. Since the developers won't recognize this is as an issue with the theme (but rather a choice to leave out alt-tags), I can't get any help from them at all.

So I found the code that outputs the img-tag for each slide. However the actual output is not there, so I can't add the alt tag manually to the code.

This is the part that renders the slides:

```
function render_slideshow(){
    if(post_password_required($this->post_id)){ return false; }
    $output = "";
    $i = 0;
    $output .= $this->before_container_html;
    if($this->slide_number){

        $output .= '<div class="slideshow_container '.esc_attr($this->slide_container_class).' slide_layout_'.esc_attr($this->options['slideshow_layout']).'" id="'.esc_attr($this->slide_container_id).'flex" '.esc_attr($this->additional_attr).'>';
        $output .= $this->custom_header_html;
        $output .= '    <ul class="'.esc_attr($this->slide_ul_class).' slide_'.esc_attr($this->slide_type).'">';
        $output .= $this->before_elements;
        foreach($this->slides as $slide):

            $i++;
            $image = "";
            if(!empty($slide['attachment_id']))
            {   
                $m_d = '';
                if(isset($this->media_img_data[$i]) && !empty($this->media_img_data[$i]))
                    $m_d = $this->media_img_data[$i];
                $image_string = codeless_image_by_id($slide['attachment_id'], $this->img_size, 'image', $m_d); 
                if(!$image_string) $image_string = $slide['attachment_id'];
                if(isset($slide['url']) && $slide['url'] != 'http://')
                {
                    $image = "<a href='".esc_url($slide['url'])."'>".$image_string."</a>";
                }else
                    $image = $image_string;
            }

            $output .= "<li class='".esc_attr($this->slide_element_class)." slide_element slide".$i." frame".$i."'>";
                if(!is_array($this->before_render_media))
                    $output .=           $this->before_render_media;
                else
                    $output .=           $this->before_render_media[$i];
                $output .=           $image;
                $output .=           $this->after_render_media;
                if(isset($slide['title']) && strlen($slide['title']) > 1){
                    $output .= $this->after_render_media; $output .= '<div class="captionss">';
           $output .= '<p class="flex-caption" data-effect-in="fadeInLeft" data-effect-out="fadeOutRight"><span>'.esc_attr($slide['title']).'</span></p>';
                       if(isset($slide['description']) && strlen($slide['description']) > 1)
            $output .= '<p class="flex-caption" data-effect-in="fadeInLeft" data-effect-out="fadeOutRight"><span>'.esc_attr($slide['description']).'</span></p>';
           $output .='</div>';
        }
            $output .= "        </li>";




        endforeach;
        $output .= $this->after_elements;
        $output .= "    </ul>";
        $output .= $this->custom_footer_html;

        $output .= "</div>";
        $output .= $this->after_container_html;

    }
    return $output;

}
```

The line that renders the actual image is this:

```
                   $image = "<a href='".esc_url($slide['url'])."'>".$image_string."</a>";
```

The image_string referred to, is just above that line. But I have no idea how to implement the alt there. Since it takes data from elsewhere, but I have no idea where to find that.

The image is rendered online as

```
<img src='https://praktijk-kerngezond.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/foto_kinderdietist_kerngezond-e1526907903126.jpg' title='foto_kinderdietist_kerngezond' alt='' />
```

As you can see the alt-tag is referred to in the code, but empty. While the value in the media library is filled in.

Anyone can point me in the right direction? I would love it to have the alt tag specified within the media library, but i would also be happy with a static all tag for all slides.

Thanks,

Regards, 
Mirna

Comment: A good start would be to search for the function name "codeless_image_by_id". I imagine it is somewhere in the themes functions.php or another file included by functions.php. It seems like that is where you need to add the image alt tag

Answer (score 0):

Static option, change:

```
if(!$image_string) $image_string = $slide['attachment_id'];
if(isset($slide['url']) && $slide['url'] != 'http://')
```

to:

```
if(!$image_string) $image_string = $slide['attachment_id'];

$image_string = str_replace("alt=''", alt="YOUR STATIC ALT", $image_string);

if(isset($slide['url']) && $slide['url'] != 'http://')
```

or use $slide['title'] if not emtpy:

```
if(!$image_string) $image_string = $slide['attachment_id'];

$slide['title'] ? $alt = $slide['title'] : $alt = "YOUR STATIC ALT"; 
$image_string = str_replace("alt=''", alt="'.$alt.'", $image_string);

if(isset($slide['url']) && $slide['url'] != 'http://')
```